# .htaccess serve index.html under all urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a possibility to rewrite .htaccess to point all request to `index.html` but without changing the url?

I found a rule that redirects all requests to index.html, but in this case, the url is changed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule . /index.html [R=302,L]
```

Is it possible to point all url addresses to `index.html` but with keeping original url?

```
mydomain.com/foo -> display index.html (address stays)
```

How to do this?

Comment: Very simple. Just remove the `R=302` flag.

Comment: @starkeen this is it. I would mark your answer as a solution if you wish to post it below. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R` flag makes an external redirection. If you do not want to redirect the url simply remove the flag from your rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: I had the index.html file in a subdirectory, so I had to remove the slash, otherwise Apache served it from document root: `RewriteRule . index.html [L]`